# External gyroscope/accelerometer for iphone

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to add a external gyroscope and accelerometer to my Iphone. I can make an app that receive these data, but I want all the other apps that use CMMotionManager in Core Motion Library to use my external gyroscope/accelerometer data rather than the built-in one. Is this even possible?

Comment: Short answer: No

Comment: Additionally, what's the point?

Comment: You can provide an SDK / API so 3rd party app developers can easily use your hardware.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have your application in which you use the SDK for the external device to read the values from it. Other apps have no way of knowing about your external sensor.